# 400 Error when requesting from OpenAI API

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, openai-api

```
var openairequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
const payload = ({
    "model": "text-davinci-003",
    "prompt": "say this is a test"
});

console.log(payload)
openairequest.open("POST",`https://api.openai.com/v1/completions?data=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(payload))}`)
openairequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
openairequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization",`Bearer ${open_ai_key}`)
```

I tried sending a XHR request to the OpenAI API completions URl to test whether the requests were working correctly and as expected

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "You didn't provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in an Authorization header using Bearer auth (i.e. Authorization: Bearer YOUR_KEY), or as the password field (with blank username) if you're accessing the API from your browser and are prompted for a username and password. You can obtain an API key from https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys.",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": null,
        "code": null
    }
}
```

This is what I got in response which is confusing as I am sure that I am passing through a JSON object

**EDIT**
I noticed that I wasn't actually sending the request so fixed that quickly, however I can't see the issue with how I'm providing the API Key through authorization

```js
var open_ai_key = "MY KEY"

var openairequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
const payload = ({
    "model": "text-davinci-003",
    "prompt": "say this is a test"
});

openairequest.open("POST",`https://api.openai.com/v1/completions?data=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(payload))}`)
openairequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
openairequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization",`Bearer ${open_ai_key}`)
openairequest.send()
console.log(openairequest)
```

**EDIT**

I managed to fix this by passing the object through `openairequest.send(JSON.stringify(payload))`

Comment: The error seems pretty clear to me. Check your browser's "Network" developer tab to see what the actual outgoing request looks like.

Comment: @Pointy I've had a look and all I can see is data: {"model":"text-davinci-003","prompt":"say this is a test"} when its decoded, is the issue that it's encoded?

Comment: What about that "Authorization" header?

Comment: Ensure that you are specifying the API key to this open_ai_key constant.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by passing the object through `openairequest.send(JSON.stringify(payload))`
I was also using a depreceated text model so changed that to the recommended `gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct`
I found this solution on [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-post-request-how-to-send-an-http-post-request-in-js/)